# 'AutoShardedBot' object has no attribute 'member_cache'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had cloned a git repo called [Pollmaster](https://github.com/matnad/pollmaster) and tried to execute the program but it had some dependency conflicts which I resolved by installing `aiohttps<3.6.0` and now the bot shows this error as seen in the image-

[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYb3S.png)

How do I resolve this error?

`Steps to repoduce this error`

`1.change requirements to aiohttps<3.6.0`

`2.type in a discord channel "pm!close" after making a poll`